# Energy measures and probability of measuring them

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian

We have the following Hamiltonian

$\hat{H}=a|u_{1}\rangle\langle u_{2}|+a|u_{2}\rangle\langle u_{1}|$

with a $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $|u_{1}\rangle,|u_{2}\rangle$ an orthonormal system

The matrix representation of $\hat{H}$ in that system is

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\
a & 0
\end{pmatrix}

the eigenvalues are a and -a, and the corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors are $|\phi_{1}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1,1)^\top$ and $|\phi_{2}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1, -1)^\top$.

Let $|\Psi(t=0)\rangle = |u_{1}\rangle$ be the state at the moment $t=0$.

**1. What are the energy values that we can measure at the moment $t=0$ and with what probabilities?**

**2. What is the state at the moment t? Which energy values can we measure at that moment and with what probabilities?**
I've found the state at time t to be $|\Psi(t)\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\exp\left(-\frac{iE_{1}}{\hbar}t\right)|\phi_{1}\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\exp\left(-\frac{iE_{2}}{\hbar}t\right)|\phi_{2}\rangle$

So, my question is, are there different values of the energy depending on the moment? For what I know, the energy values that we can measure are the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian. So in both questions 1 and 2 the energy values that we can measure are a and -a, right? And both with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. First of all about the fact that the only allowed measurement outcomes for an energy measurement are the eigenvalues of $\hat{H}$, $a$ and $-a$, regardless of the time instant in which the measurement is performed. Secondly about the fact that the probabilities are both equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ and constant over time, since  only the phases of the coefficients of the time-dependent wavefunction oscillate over time. These phases square out in the absolute values squares that yield the probabilities.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. So the only values we can measure for energy are the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian. However, the system can be found in a state that does not necessarily have to be an eigenvector of the Hamiltonian, right?

Comment: No. Well it depends. As long as you measure the energy, the only allowed post-measurement states are energy eigenstates. However, if you measure some other observable, the post-measurement state is one of the eigenstates of the given observable

Comment: That bothers me because in an exercise I did, there was this question: what is the probability of finding the system at the moment t in the state $|u_{2}\rangle$? But the state $|u_{2}\rangle$ is not an eigenstate.

Comment: This does not contradict any of our statements above: given any two orthonormal states defining a basis which spans the Hilbert space you can perform a projective measurement in this basis. These two states are related to some observable represented by an hermitian operator, whose eigenvalues are the allowed measurement results for the projective measurement.

Comment: So $|u_{2}\rangle$ is an allowed post-measurement state because we can express it as a linear combination of $|\phi_{1}\rangle$ and $|\phi_{2}\rangle$, which are the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. Did I understand right?

Comment: You can write any state out of your Hilbert space as a linear combination of the two energy eigenstates, as these form an orthonormal basis. Given any state $|\psi_{1}\rangle$ you write as a superposition of the two, there is some other superposition of them $|\psi_{2}\rangle$ which is orthonormal to $|\psi_{1}\rangle$ (i.e. $\langle \psi_{1} | \psi_{2}\rangle=0$) such that they form another orthonormal basis together. If you perform a projective measurement with respect to this basis, the post-measurement state will be either $|\psi_{1}\rangle$ or $|\psi_{2}\rangle$.

Comment: It's just that I don't understand what a projective measurement is. If we perform a projective measurement, the possible measures of the energy are still the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian (in this case a and -a) right?

Comment: Sorry maybe I just made things too complicated. A projective measurement is just a measurement in which by means of some experimental apparatus you project the state of your system onto one state of some chosen orthonormal basis. However, yes: if you are measuring the energy you do a measurement in the energy eigenstate basis. If instead you are measuring some other physical observable, say the momentum of a particle, the only allowed post-measurement states are eigenstates of the momentum operator.